# what is the meaning behind grunt-contrib-x?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gruntjs

I'm brand new to grunt and I'm looking at refs in a different grunt file that a different developer put together. I see several "contrib" refs in his code and was wondering what "contrib" represents in the grunt world:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');    
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
```

In the grunt context, does "contrib" represent a certain type of node module, a certain type of supporting module, a certain type of task grouping or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grunt-contrib-*` is a naming convention for official grunt plugins.

From the [Creating Plugins](http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins) documentation.

> Naming your task
>
> The "grunt-contrib" namespace is reserved for tasks maintained by the
>   Grunt team, please name your task something appropriate that avoids
>   that naming scheme.